# TYPO3 9.5 Speaking URL - How to rewrite/redirect former RealUrl pages suffixed .html

Tags: apache, typo3-9.x

How can I permanently rewrite or redirect former from realurl suffixed .html pages to the new implemented URL?

So far I didn't see any solution in the API Overview -> Site Handling. Or do I have to do this in the .htaccess file?

I just upgraded my website from TYPO3 8.7 LTS to 9.5 LTS.

In 8.7 I used realurl for Speaking URLs with the configuration:

```
'www.mydomain.local' =>
    array (
        'init' =>
            array (
                'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect[301]',
                'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
            ),
        'pagePath' =>
            array (
                'rootpage_id' => '1',
            ),
        'fileName' =>
            array (
                'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => true,
                'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
```

So, all my pages got a .html suffix, e.g. https://resterland.ch/webatelier.html.

After upgrading to TYPO3 9.5 LTS with the new implemented Speaking URLs Out of the Box, all pages ending without any suffix by default, e.g. https://resterland.ch/webatelier.

So far so good. However, if someone like to link to a bookmarked page with the .html suffix, they of course get an "Oops, an error occurred!".

And in the Administration log ERRORs like this:

```
Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1544172838: Error handler could not fetch error page "https://resterland.ch/", reason: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to resterland.ch port 443: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) | RuntimeException thrown in file /var/www/vhosts/resterland.ch/typo3_src-9.5.3/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Error/PageErrorHandler/PageContentErrorHandler.php in line 77. Requested URL: https://resterland.ch/webatelier.html
```

Answer (score 0):

realurl is no longer supported. you have to use the new site be modul. or for extension: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html